# Update button clears out fields that were not edited instead of leaving the default value

Tags: sql, reactjs, axios

I am having an issue that happens when the update button is clicked. It is pulling the active statues, last name, and collector code from an SQL database. If I edit only 1 field like change the Active status from true to false and click Update User then the Last Name field and Collector Code field goes blank updating those in the database to blank rows. I need it to where if you don't make a change then it just keeps what is already in there and only changes the one that was actually edited. This is using react.js, express, cors, sql, node.js, and axios.

```
                                     NEW CODE
```

````
import "./UpdateUser.css";
import axios from 'axios';

class EditUser extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    collectorList: [],
    CollectorID: props.CollectorID,
    ProgramBucketID: 'test',
    CollectorOptionsID: 'test',
    FinanceCompanyID: 'test',
    Active: props.Active || false,
    LastName: props.LastName,
    CollectorCode: props.CollectorCode,
    Aging1to15: props.Aging1to15 || false,
    Aging31to45: props.Aging31to45 || false,
    Aging31to60: props.Aging31to60 || false,
    AgingOver60: props.AgingOver60 || false,
    ProgramBucketA: props.ProgramBucketA || false,
    ProgramBucketB: props.ProgramBucketB || false,
    ProgramBucketC: props.ProgramBucketC || false,
    ProgramBucketSU: props.ProgramBucketSU || false,
    FinanceCompany: props.FinanceCompany
  }
  this.handleActiveChange = this.handleActiveChange.bind(this);
  this.handleAging115Change = this.handleAging115Change.bind(this);
  this.handleAging3145Change = this.handleAging3145Change.bind(this);
  this.handleAging3160Change = this.handleAging3160Change.bind(this);
  this.handleAgingOver60Change = this.handleAgingOver60Change.bind(this);
  this.handleProgramAChange = this.handleProgramAChange.bind(this);
  this.handleProgramBChange = this.handleProgramBChange.bind(this);
  this.handleProgramCChange = this.handleProgramCChange.bind(this);
  this.handleProgramSUChange = this.handleProgramSUChange.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount(e) {
  this.getCollectors()
}

handleActiveChange() {
  this.setState({ 
    Active: !this.state.Active,
    CollectorID: this.state.CollectorID,
    CollectorOptionsID: this.state.CollectorOptionsID,
    ProgramBucketID: this.state.ProgramBucketID,
    FinanceCompanyID: this.state.FinanceCompanyID
  })
}

handleAging115Change() {
  this.setState({ 
    Aging1to15: !this.state.Aging1to15
  })
  console.log(this.state.CollectorID,', ', this.state.CollectorOptionsID,', ', this.state.ProgramBucketID,', ', this.state.FinanceCompanyID);
}

handleAging3145Change() {
  this.setState({ 
    Aging31to45: !this.state.Aging31to45
  })
}

handleAging3160Change() {
  this.setState({ 
    Aging31to60: !this.state.Aging31to60
  })
}

handleAgingOver60Change() {
  this.setState({ 
    AgingOver60: !this.state.AgingOver60
  })
}

handleProgramAChange() {
  this.setState({
    ProgramBucketA: !this.state.ProgramBucketA
  })
}

handleProgramBChange() {
  this.setState({
    ProgramBucketB: !this.state.ProgramBucketB
  })
}

handleProgramCChange() {
  this.setState({
    ProgramBucketC: !this.state.ProgramBucketC
  })
}

handleProgramSUChange() {
  this.setState({
    ProgramBucketSU: !this.state.ProgramBucketSU
  })
}
  
  getCollectors = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/getCollectors')
    .then((result) => result.data)
    .then((result) => {
      this.setState({collectorList: result});
      console.log(result);
    });
  };

  onUpdateClick = CollectorID => {
    axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/UpdateUser/${CollectorID}`, {
      CollectorID: this.state.CollectorID,
      CollectorOptionsID: this.state.CollectorOptionsID,
      ProgramBucketID: this.state.ProgramBucketID,
      FinanceCompanyID: this.state.FinanceCompanyID,
      Active: this.state.Active,  
      LastName: this.state.LastName,
      CollectorCode: this.state.CollectorCode,
      Aging1to15: this.state.Aging1to15,
      Aging31to45: this.state.Aging31to45,
      Aging31to60: this.state.Aging31to60,
      AgingOver60: this.state.AgingOver60,
      ProgramBucketA: this.state.ProgramBucketA,
      ProgramBucketB: this.state.ProgramBucketB,
      ProgramBucketC: this.state.ProgramBucketC,
      ProgramBucketSU: this.state.ProgramBucketSU,
      FinanceCompany: this.state.FinanceCompany
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="newUser">
        <h1 className="newUserTitle">Collector Update Forms</h1>
        {this.state.collectorList.map((Collectors) => (
          <form className="newUserForm" key={Collectors.CollectorID}>
        <div className="newUserItem">
          <b>{Collectors.FirstName} {Collectors.LastName} | {Collectors.CollectorCode} | ID: {Collectors.CollectorID}</b>
          {/*Active or inactive User*/}
            <label>Active Status</label>
            <input
                type='checkbox'
                name="Active"
                defaultChecked={Collectors.Active === false ? false : true}
                value={this.state.Active}
                onChange={e => this.setState({
                    Active: !this.state.Active,
                    CollectorCode: e.target.value = Collectors.CollectorID
                  })}
                />
          {/*Collector Last Name*/}
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="LastName"
              defaultValue={Collectors.LastName} 
              onChange={e => this.setState({
                LastName: e.target.value
              })}
            />
          {/*Collector Code First Initial Middle Initial Last Initial*/}
             <label>Collector Code</label>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="CollectorCode"
              defaultValue={Collectors.CollectorCode} 
              onChange={e => this.setState({
                CollectorCode: e.target.value
              })}
            />

            <label>Collector ID</label>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="CollectorID"
              defaultValue={Collectors.CollectorID} 
              onChange={e => this.setState({
                CollectorID: e.target.value = Collectors.CollectorID
              })}
            />

            {/*Aging Bucket selection section */}
            <label>Aging Bucket</label>
             <div className='newUserCheckboxContainer'>
             <label className='newUserCheckboxLabel'>1-15<br/>
              <input
                type='checkbox'
                className='AgingBucketCheckbox'
                name="Aging1to15"
                defaultChecked={Collectors.Aging1to15 === false ? false : true}
                value={this.state.Aging1to15} 
                onChange={this.handleAging115Change}
              /></label>
              <label className='newUserCheckboxLabel'>31-45<br/>
              <input
                type='checkbox'
                className='AgingBucketCheckbox'
                name="Aging31to45"
                defaultChecked={Collectors.Aging31to45 === false ? false : true}
                value={this.state.Aging31to45} 
                onChange={this.handleAging3145Change}
              /></label>
              <label className='newUserCheckboxLabel'>31-60<br/>
              <input
                type='checkbox'
                className='AgingBucketCheckboxsm'
                name="Aging31to60"
                defaultChecked={Collectors.Aging31to60 === false ? false : true}
                value={this.state.Aging31to60} 
                onChange={this.handleAging3160Change}
              /></label>
              <label className='newUserCheckboxLabel'>Over 60<br/>
              <input
                type='checkbox'
                className='AgingBucketCheckboxlg'
                name="AgingOver60"
                defaultChecked={Collectors.AgingOver60 === false ? false : true}
                value={this.state.AgingOver60} 
                onChange={this.handleAgingOver60Change}
              /></label>
            </div>
            {/*Progam code selection section*/}
            <label>Program Bucket</label>
            <div className='newUserCheckboxContainer'>
              <label className='newUserCheckboxLabel'>A<br/>
              <input
                type='checkbox'
                className='ProgramCodeChecbox'
                name="ProgramBucketA"
                defaultChecked={Collectors.ProgramBucketA === false ? false : true}
                value={this.state.ProgramBucketA} 
                onChange={this.handleProgramAChange}
              /></label>
              <label className='newUserCheckboxLabel'>B<br/>
              <input
                type='checkbox'
                className='ProgramCodeChecbox'
                name="ProgramBucketB"
                defaultChecked={Collectors.ProgramBucketB === false ? false : true}
                value={this.state.ProgramBucketB} 
                onChange={this.handleProgramBChange}
              /></label>
              <label className='newUserCheckboxLabel'>C<br/>
              <input
                type='checkbox'
                className='ProgramCodeChecbox'
                name="ProgramBucketC"
                defaultChecked={Collectors.ProgramBucketC === false ? false : true}
                value={this.state.ProgramBucketC} 
                onChange={this.handleProgramCChange}
              /></label>
              <label className='newUserCheckboxLabel'>SU<br/>
              <input
                type='checkbox'
                className='ProgramCodeChecbox'
                name="ProgramBucketSU"
                defaultChecked={Collectors.ProgramBucketSU === false ? false : true}
                value={this.state.ProgramBucketSU} 
                onChange={this.handleProgramSUChange}
              /></label>
            </div>
            {/*Finance Company selection section*/}
            <div className='newUserItem'>
            <label>Finance Company</label>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="FinanceCompany"
              defaultValue={Collectors.FinanceCompany} 
              onChange={e => this.setState({
                FinanceCompany: e.target.value
              })}
            />
            </div>
            <button type="button" className="updateUserButton" onClick={() => this.onUpdateClick(Collectors.CollectorID) }>Update User</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default EditUser;```
````

Answer (score 0):

1. In "handleChange", you are modifying only specific field(Ex:"Active") and remaining fields will be not modified. Hence they will be having default values which is empty string/blank('').
2. In your "onUpdateClick" handler, you are submitting data by referring to the component state. Only the field that you have modified explicitly will be holding the recent value other fields will be having empty string/blank(''). In your case, when you submit your request, you are passing empty values for "lastName", "Collector Code"[If you have modified "Active", it will be having recent value].
3. Simple fix would be modifying the "collectorsList" for every changes. Pass "collectorId" to "handleChange" and filter the "collector" object that matches "collectorId", modify the required properties values. In "onUpdateClick" handler, you are already passing the "collectorId", filter the collector object that matches the collectorId. Filtered object will be holding the valid values[modified values and old values that are not modified]. Pass that object properties in your "put" request.
4. Above approach is bit time consuming, if you are dealing with huge "collectorsList". It would be better if you redesign the state and add additional handlers to make component optimized.

Comment: Would you be able to assist in the redesign of this as I have made a bunch of changes and still not working the best but feel I am getting closer. I am going to edit the question with the new way I am trying this.

Comment: Could you please create a sandbox or any similar and push your code, so that we can work on efficiently and resolve the issues.

Comment: How would I do that with a react app project I have not done that before. This data is all coming from an SQL database.

Comment: If this is your personal project and if it is in GitHub, you can pull the code to codesandbox. Before pulling, create react sandbox. You can install all the libraries required for your application.
https://codesandbox.io/framework/react

Comment: OK, I can do that but this is a work DB so I can't add the file with username and password unless you know how to make it so they are not sent over as I have not done anything like that before.

Comment: You can create test data with similar that you are using in your component. we won't be dealing with CRUD operations. You can store test data in any object within the component. we can make use of it in redesigning.

Comment: The styling is horrible right now in the sandbox but I think I got it in there now at https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-forest-hbh26h

The area I am working on is under Users > Edit Collector

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243624/discussion-between-b-anup-and-meef).